# What's the minimum equipment rating required to perform testing in production environment?

Tags: standard, test-equipment

I would like to purchase a Power supply to test my unit in production environment. The power supply is expected to support a production yield of **1 Million units per year**. As per one of the test requirements, I am required to supply/output 100 Amps of current for 5 seconds at 2Volts DC. One of the DC supply I am looking at could supply 110A at 10V. I want to know if it's a good idea to buy this power supply since it rated for only 10% above the maximum UUT required current.

Could someone name a Standard (any free resources if available on the internet) that would contain such guidelines?
Thank you.

Comment: This question will likely be closed as either needs focus (since you are asking multiple things) or off-topic (since one of the questions is a purchasing recommendation). You should narrow this down to a single question and make sure the title agrees with the body of the question.

Comment: You need to qualify the test as part of your overall production plan. Sometimes it is impossible on paper to understand if a particular device will meet your requirements - you may need to buy it or rent it to understand if it will work or not. A rule of thumb: the tester should test the product, the product should not test the tester. MTBF is a function of component stress (volts, amps, degrees) - the closer you run something to flat-out, the shorter it will last. I doubt there is a comprehensive standard for this.

Comment: People make hi pot testers that do all the testing for you

Comment: Talk to a regulatory consultant, they'll be your best resource

Answer (score 1):

You will be cycling this power supply at 5,000 events per day, for 200 days a year, to reach the 1,000,000 goal. This is every 18 seconds, at 3 shifts a day.

Chances are the thermal cycling will cause quick failure.

So chat with the manufacturer, especially the Reliability or Quality people.